# dart proxy objects can or cannot be assigned to typed variables?

Tags: dart, proxy-object

I have the following test code:

```dart
@proxy
class A{
  noSuchMethod(Invocation inv) => "no problems";
}

class B{
  String get aString => "I'm a B string";
}

void main() {
  B b = new A();
  print(b.aString);
}
```

from what I read on the [api site](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core#id_proxy) about proxy, I assumed it would be ok to assign a proxy to anything without getting a TypeError at runtime, but that isn't the case here. What is the point in having proxies implement essentially anything they want if they can't be assigned to anything without getting TypeErrors thrown. in the docs it says it isnt a static type error to assign a proxy to any variable type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@proxy` is used to avoid warnings.

```dart
class A{
  noSuchMethod(Invocation inv) => "no problems";
}

@proxy
class B{
  noSuchMethod(Invocation inv) => "no problems";
}

void main() {
  A a = new A();
  B b = new B();

  a.something; // warning
  b.something; // no warning
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? @proxy does not fix the TypeError :-/